# How can I add key value pairs to JSON where type is bytes?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I tried adding key value to JSON type bytes.
But displaying below error:

```
TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
```

Below is my code

```
conn.request("GET", "/api/watches/REST", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read() #byte

data['target'] = 'omni'
```

My JSON output is like this:

```
[{"Value":23,"Unit":"°C","WatchName":"AvgSFTemp Present Value"},{"Value":"Normal","WatchName":"FAR Present Value"}]
```

Desired ouput

```
[{"target":"omni","Value":23,"Unit":"°C","WatchName":"AvgSFTemp Present Value"},{"target":"omni","Value":"Normal","WatchName":"FAR Present Value"}]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "my json output"? Your Python code isn't printing that and `data` is not json... JSON doesn't have a bytes type

Answer (score 0):

It's because what you get with res.read() is byte, not dict
So you need to use the python json library like so

```
import json

...

conn.request("GET", "/api/watches/REST", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = json.loads(res.read()) #byte

data['target'] = 'omni'
```

json.loads() takes a string or a byte object representing a text json and loads it into a dictionary so you can use it as an object

Comment: Assuming `conn` is from the requests library, `res.json()` works too. Also, OP says data is a list, not a dict

Comment: @Moreo Thanks for your reply. I tried it but it comes with error. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: where does this exception occur ?